# What is the FXMLLoader load method really doing?

Tags: java, model-view-controller, javafx

I have this javaFX interface consisting of a root layout which is a simple BorderPane. And two AnchorPane which I want to alternatively set in the center of the rootLayout when a button is pushed on the rootLayout menu.
It's working alright but there is one thing I'm having trouble to understand.
I am calling a method with the rootlayout controller when the button is pushed. And although it should only be executed once it is executed twice !

To give the basic idea, here's what the code involved look like :

method handling the button action, located in the root layout controller :

```
@FXML
private void handleStockWizardButton(){
    mainApp.updateProduct(0,10);
    mainApp.showStockWizard();
}
```

It's filling an Observable list which is later passed to the second page controller in order to display them in a table view. the method to display this view and set every thing is the following :

```
public void showStockWizard(){
    try {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        loader.setLocation(MainApp.class.getResource("view/StockWizard.fxml"));
        AnchorPane StockWizard = (AnchorPane) loader.load();
        rootLayout.setCenter(StockWizard);
        StockWizardController controller = loader.getController();
        controller.setMainApp(this);
        controller.setProduct(product);
    } catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

what is bothering me here is that on the loader.load() call the handleStockWizardButton() method, although not related to the constructor present here, is called!
Is there some aspect of the load method I am missing ?

EDIT :

Here are some more code involved :

controller of the view to display, setting some value factories and set some listener, nothing that should send back to the root controller :

```
@FXML
private void initialize(){
    productNameColumn.setCellValueFactory(CellData -> CellData.getValue().nameProperty());
    productReferenceColumn.setCellValueFactory(CellData -> CellData.getValue().referenceProperty());
    productUnitSellingPriceColumn.setCellValueFactory(CellData -> CellData.getValue().unitSellingPriceProperty());
    displayChoices.add("10");
    displayChoices.add("25");
    displayChoices.add("50");
    displayChoiceBox.setItems(displayChoices);
    displayChoiceBox.setValue("10");
    displayChoiceBox.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> setDisplayValue());
    currentPage.setText("1");
}
```

The details of the updateproducts methods would be of no use here since it's just accessing a web service and processing the lines recieved. it is quite clean.

Here is the FXML file for the rootlayout borderPane, what is to notice here is the menu item that calls handleButton on action :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>

<BorderPane minHeight="540.0" prefHeight="720.0" prefWidth="1280.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.40" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="prestashopwebservice.view.RootController">
   <top>
      <MenuBar BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
        <menus>
          <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleConfigure" text="Configuration">
               <items>
                  <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleConfigure" text="open configuration" />
               </items></Menu>
            <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleStockWizard" text="StockWizard">
               <items>
                  <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleStockWizardButton" text="open StockWizard" />
               </items></Menu>
        </menus>
      </MenuBar>
   </top>
</BorderPane>
```

Comment: It is impossible that an FXMLLoader on load of FXML#1 calls a method of a Controller which is associated with FXML#2. The FXMLLoader simply creates an instance of the associated controller and calls initialize() method on that (beside of the XML parsing and injection of course). Please post full code.

Comment: Posted some more code. It should be plenty to have an idea of what is happening in details here.

Comment: you really need to learn about [code conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html), your current code is horrible and hard to read ... almost all developers are used to reading camelCase whereas you are writing uppercase variables and whatnot ... also : *"handleButton"* is confusing because it could mean "handle **any** button", instead you should name the method something like "onStickWizardButton" or even "onActionStockWizard" or something - thats really important if you want other developers to read your code **and** help you

Comment: Understood for the naming of the methods. However, I thought I had the camelCase convention right. Can you please quote an example from here so that I can see where I got the convention wrong ?

Comment: click the link ... how hard can that be

Comment: I know, I went there, read the whole thing (which I already did in the past). But I still can't see where I made a mistake with the convention. Especially with the camelCase. However, I admit some of the name I used could be clearer.

Comment: `StockWizard` should be `stockWizard`, `CellData` should be `cellData`, etc.

Comment: okay, note taken, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `onAction` event will be propagated up through the menu structure, unless consumed. Therefore if you click the `open configuration` `MenuItem` and `handleConfigure` doesn't consume the event, it will be triggered again for the `Configuration` `Menu`.

Prevent this by calling [`Event.consume`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/event/Event.html#consume--) in the handler methods, e.g.

```
@FXML
private void handleConfigure(ActionEvent evt) {
    ...

    evt.consume();
}
```

or simply remove the `onAction` attributes from the `Menu`s (they could be replaced with `onShown` or `onHidden`, if necessary).

Comment: Perfect, the event consumer did the trick and I now understand a bit more about events. thanks !